# Show that a function oscillates between two points?

Tags: calculus, kinematics

For the function $\text{cos} (x),$ how do I show a function oscillates between two points? This question was posed to me as part of a kinematics question in differential calculus. I know how to show the period of $\text{cos} (x)$ is $2\pi$ but I know showing the period is not enough. Should I find the maximum, $y = 1,$ and minimum, $y= -1,$ and show they are periodic also?

Comment: See if this site can help you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143441/mix-plot-with-cos-and-points

Comment: Not exactly what you need, but it's an option

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but if you're asking how to show that the function $\cos(x)$ has no limit and takes the values $1, -1$ infinite times you can start by noticing that, since the function is periodic (and non-constant) it has no limit; than you observe that $\cos(x)=1\implies x=2k\pi$ and $\cos(x)=-1\implies x=\pi+2k\pi$ where $k$ can be replaced by any  natural number: so $\cos(x)$ takes these values (that are maximum and minimum of $\cos(x)$) infinite times, and you can state that your function oscillates between two points.

Comment: yes, this was what i was trying to say when i said "showing the maximum and minimum are periodic" however i think your method of showing 'oscillation' is better. not sure what my teacher wants exactly but this is a good start